# Python - make graph from MySql database

Tags: python, mysql, graph

I need to make graph(Python dictionary) from MySql database - graph with database structure, I don't care about data. For every table in DB I need list of columns and list of children, where children are foreign keys(only table name where foreign key is).

Is there any smart Pythonic way to do that?

Database is MySql and Python3.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: ER diagram or Graph data ?

Comment: I need dict that I will later visualise using D3, but that is not important. For example: 
`result = [
   {'output" : {"table_name": "employee", "id":"integer no null"}, "children" : "[]"},
'output" : {"table_name": "table2", "id2":"varchar(2)"}, "children" : "["emloyee"]"}]`